# Mysql inner join with relational table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have this tables :

```
tbl_article
 -id
 -title
 -category_id

tbl_rel_article_category
 -id
 -article_id
 -category_id

tbl_category
 -id
 -title
```

and I need a query to find the articles that have:

`(tbl_article.category_id=X OR tbl_rel_article_category.category_id=X)`

Is possible have the result in one query without union?

Thx.
MS

Comment: Your question doesn't make too much sense to me because the two `WHERE` conditions appear to be saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this query:

```
SELECT id.tbl_article, id.tbl_rel_article_category 
FROM tbl_article 
INNER JOIN tbl_rel_article_category
ON id.tbl_article = article_id.tbl_rel_article_category
WHERE (tbl_article.category_id=X OR tbl_rel_article_category.category_id=X)
```